# Should I delete this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deletion, deleted-questions

Today I asked the following question here:

[Domain of multiplication operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885449/domain-of-multiplication-operator/885454#885454)

As it turned out, it was a foolish question on my part. I had made a silly mistake. Should I delete it now because future readers will waste their time in reading that only to find out that it was no good?

But somehow, deleting it feels unjust to those who took time to answer and comment.

What should be done with this question?

Comment: You cannot delete it as it has an answer with positive score.

Comment: Incidentally, I upvoted the answer. so I could remove it and still delete.

Comment: Not unless you upvoted less than 5 minutes ago (or edit the answer). Instead, just add a short sentence to the start of the question indicating your misunderstanding.

Comment: Minor comment: ``TeX-style'' quotation marks don't look good here. Better to use the "normal" quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

A redeeming feature of your question is that sets a good example of how "confused when reading something" questions should be asked.

> In his book, ``Linear Operators on Hilbert Spaces'', Weidmann claims (on Page 52, Example 2)

it **so much better** than "I'm reading a paper where the author says..."

It is amazing how many people ask in the latter form, with no indication of the source (hence no way for others to find the   context that they are missing). If they read your question, they might learn how it should be done, so there's that.