# Should I erase this question

Tags: discussion, deletion, self-answer

I asked a question about series summations and my verification attempts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472449/summation-in-the-form-of-jacobi-theta-function). Later, I solved the question with the summation limits, i.e., my verification code in python did not take all indices into account. In my experience, most of the similar questions have this problem in their root.

After solving it, I added a comment that I solved it and briefly mention the problem in the comment. I think this specific question might only help a very small group of people, and the size of the group can be as small as zero.

I also do not want people to spend unnecessary amount of time there. So, I have two options:

- Delete the question
- Answer it myself

Which one should I choose? What are the general principles to approach in these situations?

Previous but not comprehensive meta discussion on a very similar situation can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/should-i-delete-this-question).

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself!  You persisted and found the answer; go ahead and answer your question.

Comment: Put another way, please don't delete your question. You put a lot of time and effort into writing it, and also persevering to try and answer it.  I encourage you to answer your question!

Comment: @amWhy Thanks! I crafted a solution now.

Comment: C.Koka Nice work!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can add the solution with correct approach to solve the problem as an answer. The point is to have questions which help most people in future. If you can summarize your work and write down the issue, even if a person who doesn't have exact same issue (same problem statement) comes, then they will find benefit from your question (unless a dupe). If your question is a dupe, then you can self close your question as a dupe.

In my personal experience, dupe closing is helpful because it helps me find the question which has best answers quickly. Otherwise I end up clicking links in circles till I return to the original link I viewed.

Comment: Thanks! No, I do not think it is a duplicate. It is just that when summations don't add up, summation limits are the problem for the majority of the cases and it is no different for my question as well.

Comment: If the particular problem is unique keep it, otherwise, close it as dupe of the older version of it. This way a person won't have to browse much before reaching the better answers @C.Koca